# if $C$ is a vector space over a finite field $\mathbb{F_q}$ where q is prime, and $|C|=q^n, n\in \mathbb{N}$, then $dim(C)=n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

If $C$ is a vector space over a finite field $\mathbb{F_q}$ where q is prime, and the number of different vectors in the vector space is $q^n, n\in \mathbb{N}$, then $dim(C)=n$ ?

It seems to me very simple, since the if $dim(C)>n$ then $|C|>q^n$ which contradicts that $|C|=q^n$, and $dim(C)<n$ then $|C|<q^n$ which again contradicts that $|C|=q^n$. The question is whether it's the right way, and if I need to prove something in addition to what I said?

Comment: I would also explain why $\dim(C)>n$ implies $|C|>q^n$ and similarly, $\dim(C)<n$ implies $|C|<q^n$. Although your approach is fine and correct, reasoning also has a significant role in math. So, it would be better to explain the reasoning of these implications using the properties of the basis.

Comment: @ArsenBerk It's simply because if $dim(C)=k$, there is $k$ basis vectors and any combination of them is unique, and there are $q^k$ different combinations since there are $k$ coefficients and each one can get $q$ different values, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. This is what I was talking about :)

Answer (score 1):

You could reason as follows: any finite dimensional vector space $V$ of dimension $r$ over a field $K$ is necessarily isomorphic to $K^r$, and thus when $K$ is finite, we will have $|V|=|K^r|=|K|^r$.

Therefore if $|C|=q^n$, and $|K|=|\mathbb F_q|=q$, then the dimension of $C$ must be $n$.

Of course, your argument also works (and is probably equivalent), but you need to explain *why* $\operatorname{dim}C>n$ implies $|C|>n$ and similarly for the other case. It's not so clear how the logic flows, as it currently stands.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the statement that any finite dimensional vector space $V$ of dimension $r$ over a field $K$ is necessarily isomorphic to $K^r$, and I will look at that. What about the explanations I gave in the respond to @ArsenBerk ?

Comment: @Mr.O Yup, that's correct. Although then you wouldn't need to split cases and get a contradiction, as you already have the $|C|=q^k$ result directly.